# Buffering expectations using `printf`

Tags: c

Say there exists a C program that executes in some Linux process. Upon start, the C program calls `setvbuf` to disable buffering on `stdout`. The program then alternates between two "logical" calls ("logical" in this sense to avoid consideration of the compiler possibly reordering instructions) - the first to `printf()` and the second incrementing a variable.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    unsigned int a = 0;
    for (;;) {
        printf("hello world!");
        a++;
    }

}
```

At some point assume the program receives a signal, e.g. via `kill`, that causes the program to terminate. Will the contents of `stdout` always be complete after the signal is received, in the sense that they include the result of all previous invocations to `printf()`, or is this dependent on other levels of buffering/other behavior not controllable via `setvbuf` (e.g. kernel buffering)?

The broader context of this question is, if using a synchronous logging mechanism in a C application (e.g. all threads log with  `printf()`), can the log be trusted to be "complete" for all calls that have returned from `printf()` upon receiving some application-terminating signal?

Edit: I've edited the code snippet and question to remove undefined behavior for clarity.

Comment: A segmentation fault is practically always the result of undefined behavior. If you cause undefined behavior, you can't count on anything being in a consistent state.

Comment: You describe code. Better show it as a [mre].

Comment: @Barmar You are right on the C level, but it looks like the question is more about the underlying OS mechanism. So probably it is OS-specific.

Comment: However, if you've disabled output buffering on the stream, I think it's reasonably safe to assume that anything that was written before the undefined behavior occurred will be in the file. Logging libraries use `fflush()` after each message for the same reason.

Comment: At the OS level, it would be very unusual for a segmentation fault to have any effect on files.

Comment: *"can the log be trusted to be "complete" upon receiving some application-terminating signal?"* - this is impossible to answer. It highly depends on the exact code used, the underlying OS, environment and shell setup.

Comment: @Yunnosch this feels pedantic; however, if following the site guidelines to the letter in this case helps clarify the question being asked I'm happy to add this.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli What does the shell have to do with this? It's not involved in how programs interact with the OS.

Comment: I would argue that it is not guaranteed. Think of a not-so-common case where the `stdout` is redirected to a printer or some other teletype-like device. It will have its own "buffer" and its actual output is very slow. Now consider a segfault is happening when the printing is still underway. The OS might chose to send some special signal to interrupt the printing in that case. Or it might chose not to.

Comment: Your choice. Following recommendations on [ask] is not required. It just turned out millions of times to get more, better answers sooner. StackOverflow users simply love to see code, possibly beyond really rational extend. If you play to that, you usually benefit. It is like a cheat mode.

Comment: @Yunnosch appreciate the feedback, thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Barmar a shell can set up a lot of things that influence the program behavior, like I/O redirection, overriding of buffering policy, trapping of signals that would normally cause the program to abort, memory usage limits, etc.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Anything is possible, but in my 40 years of experience I don't think I've ever heard of something like that.

Comment: Anyway, if something like that is happening, there's not much the program can do about it. Ideally you should never cause a segfault. But since nothing is perfect, the best you can do is flush output as often as possible, and hope that the OS doesn't do anything perverted like that.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That would depend upon whether the implementation recognizes the possibility that a `printf` might block waiting on an external event that doesn't happen before the program is forcibly terminated, or that the `printf` call itself might cause the program to be forcibly terminated because of e.g. a broken pipe.

Comment: "Assume that the compiler does not reorder any instructions." is not a viable assumption, that is built into the definition of the language . This question can only be about some specific compiler behaviour under specific circumstances

Comment: @M.M - I don't think this is important to the question's formulation. The purpose of stating this assumption (whether viable or not) is to focus the question on the interface between `printf()` and the system in which the application is executing, not on a particular compiler's instruction ordering.

Comment: @rambo the compiler might notice the undefined behaviour and abort the program on startup ; or anything else. There is never any guarantee in the language standard about partial output of a program where execution reaches undefined behaviour (which it must do if a segfault was generated unless you `raise` it specifically or something).  So your question is necessarily about specifics of a particular compiler implementation and execution environment

Comment: @M.M, thanks - I've edited the question to remove the undefined behavior.

Comment: [This documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) states `When an output stream is unbuffered, information appears on the destination file or terminal as soon as written`

Answer (score 1):

Any sane interpretation of the expression "unbuffered stream" means that the data has left the stream object when `printf` returns. In the case of file-descriptor backed streams, that means the data has entered kernel-space, and the kernel should continue sending the data to its final destination (assuming no kernel panic, power loss etc).

But a problem with segfaults is that they may not happen when you think they do. Take for instance the following code:

```
int *p = NULL;
printf("hello world\n");
*p = 1;
```

A dumb non-optimizing compiler may create code that segfaults at `*p=1;`. But that is not the only possibility according to the c-standard. A compiler may for instance, if it can prove that `printf` doesn't depend on the contents of `*p`, reorganize the code like this:

```
int *p = NULL;
*p = 1; 
printf("hello world\n");
```

In that case `printf` would never be called.

Another possibility is that, since `p==NULL`, `*p=1` is invalid, the compiler may scrap that expression all together.

EDIT: The poster has changed the question from "Segfaulting" to being killed. In that case, it should all depend on if the kernel closes open file descriptors on exit the same way as `close` does, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Given a construct like:

```
fprintf(file1, "whatever"); fflush(file1);
file2 = fopen(someExistingFile, "w");
```

there are some circumstances where it may be essential that `fopen` doesn't overwrite the existing file unless or until the write to file1 can be guaranteed successful, but there are others where waiting until success of the `fflush` can be assured before starting the `fopen` would needlessly degrade performance.  In order to allow designers of C implementations to weigh such considerations however they see fit, and also avoid requiring that implementations provide semantic guarantees beyond those offered by the underlying OS (e.g. if an OS reports that the `fflush()` is complete before data is written to disk, and offers no way of finding out when all pending writes are complete, there would be no way the Standard could usefully require that an implementation which targets that OS must not allow `fflush` to return at any time when the write could still fail).

Answer (score -1):

So, it appears that there's a basic misunderstanding in your question, and I think it's important to go through the basics of what printf is -> if your stdout buffer size is 0, then the question of "will all data be sent out of the buffer" is always yes, since there isn't a hardware buffer to save data, in theory. That is, somewhere in your computer hardware there's a something like a UART chip, that has a small buffer for transferring data. Most programs I've seen do not use this hardware buffer, so It's not surprising that your program does this.

However, the printf function has an upper layer buffer (in my application ~150 characters), and I'm assuming that this is the buffer you're asking about, note that this is not the same thing as the stdout buffer, its just an allocated piece of memory that stores messages before they're sent to wherever you want them to go. Think about it - if there were no printf-specific buffer you would only be able to send 1 character per function call

Now it really depends on the implementation of printf on your system, if it's nonblocking or blocking. If it's nonblocking, that could mean that data is being transferred by an interrupt or a DMA, probably a combination of both. In which case it depends on if your system stops these transfer mechanisms in the middle of a transfer, or allows them to complete. It's impossible for me to say based on the information you've given

However, in my experience, printf is usually a blocking function; that is it locks up the rest of your code while it's transferring things out of the buffer and moves to the next command only once it's completed, in which case if you have stopped the code from running (again, I'm not certain on the specifics of "kill" in your system) then you have also stopped the transfer.

Your system most likely has blocking PRINTF calls, and considering you say a "kill" signal it sounds like you're not even really sure what you mean by that. I think it's safe to assume that whatever signal you're talking about is not internally stopping your printf function from completing, so your full message will probably be sent before exiting, even if it arrives mid-printf. If your printf is being called it most likely is completing and sending the full message, unless this "kill" signal does something odd. That's the best answer I can give you from a "C" standpoint - if you would like a more absolute answer you would have to give us information that lets us see the implementation of "printf" on your operating system, and/or give us more specifics on how this "kill signal" you mentioned works